# openCV - anpr system. Improve success rate

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to write a very good ANPR (automatic number plate recognition) system for Brazil's cars plates. So far I have used the javaANPR method which is the X and Y projection to find the ROI (car plate). It works well but not so good with image that has a lot of shadow in the car. And I am using tesseract-ocr as well for character recognition.

I got 80% of success for really good car images, from cars not moving.

And I got less than 60% for not so good images from moving cars.

I have been resourcing online, reading papers, etc. What do you think could help me improve it ? Maybe marge two methods ? Use templateMatch as well ? Because I need about 95% - 98% of success rate.

I see the anpronline
Their demo:  https://www.anpronline.net/demo.html

They have done a really good job. It worked on 100% of my images.

Are you guys aware of what OCR engine do they use ? Maybe this is a top secret.

But can you guys point me to the right direction of how to improve my OCR ?

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that any highly successful system has already been patented or classified as a trade secret. If you are not doing this for a business you could try and find the patent and replicate from that. Alternatively you could look in the scientific literature for state of the art algorithms. [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) is a pretty good search engine for that kind of search.